# Store async callback in map

Tags: rust

I'm trying to store multiple async callbacks in a single hash map which I later iterate over. This is my closest attempt to getting it working however, I'm getting a compilation error because the lifetime of the callback.

```
use std::boxed::Box;
use std::collections::HashMap;
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

type AsyncCallback = Box<dyn Fn() -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()>>>>;

#[derive(Default)]
pub struct CallbackMap {
    callbacks: HashMap<&'static str, AsyncCallback>,
}

impl CallbackMap {
    pub fn add<C, F>(&mut self, name: &'static str, callback: C)
    where
        C: Fn() -> F,
        C: 'static,
        F: Future<Output = ()> + 'static,
    {
        self.callbacks
            .insert(name, Box::new(|| Box::pin(callback())));
    }

    pub async fn execute(&self) {
        for (_key, value) in &self.callbacks {
            value().await;
        }
    }
}

async fn async_callback() {
    println!("Callback 2");
}

fn main() {
    let mut callbacks = CallbackMap::default();

    callbacks.add("test1", || async {
        println!("Callback 1");
    });

    callbacks.add("test2", async_callback);

    callbacks.execute();
}
```

Here is the error I'm getting:

```
error[E0597]: `callback` does not live long enough
  --> src/main.rs:21:48
   |
21 |             .insert(name, Box::new(|| Box::pin(callback())));
   |                           ---------------------^^^^^^^^----
   |                           |        |           |
   |                           |        |           borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                           |        value captured here
   |                           cast requires that `callback` is borrowed for `'static`
22 |     }
   |     - `callback` dropped here while still borrowed
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `move` keyword to *move* `callback` into the closure:

```
self.callbacks
    .insert(name, Box::new(move || Box::pin(callback())));
                        // ^^^^
```

Comment: Playground link: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=b07b0d49fcd93c7a366cc575c86ac31d